# Decrypting a pdf file

Tags: python, enums, python-pdfreader

So I am trying to decrypt the pdf file by using brute force approach.
The "pdfReader.decrypt(password)" returns a ENUM for type PasswordType.
I am not able to figure out how do I compare this enum to print the message that the file is decrypted successfully.

The code below is says that the object returned by pdfReader.decrypt() is of type enum, but I do not know how to retreive and compare against the value

```
import PyPDF2 as pd

filename = input('Path to the file: ')
filename = filename.strip()
file = open(filename,'rb')
pdfReader = pd.PdfReader(file)

tried = 0

if not pdfReader.is_encrypted:
    print('The file is not password protected! You can successfully open it!')

else:
    wordListFile = open('wordlist.txt', 'r',errors='ignore')
    body = wordListFile.read().lower()
    words = body.split('\n')


    for i in range(len(words)):
        word = words[i]
        print('Trying to decode passowrd by: {}'.format(word))
        result = pdfReader.decrypt(word)
        print(result,type(result))
        if result == 0:
            print('Success! The password is: '+ word)
            break
        elif result == 1:
            tried += 1
            print('Passwords tried: ' + str(tried))
            continue
```

> Output I recieved is:

```
Trying to decode passowrd by: hi
PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED <enum 'PasswordType'>
Passwords tried: 1
Trying to decode passowrd by: there
PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED <enum 'PasswordType'>
Passwords tried: 2
Trying to decode passowrd by: 0002
PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED <enum 'PasswordType'>
Passwords tried: 3
Trying to decode passowrd by: 0149
PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED <enum 'PasswordType'>
Passwords tried: 4
Trying to decode passowrd by: 0489
PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED <enum 'PasswordType'>
Passwords tried: 5
Trying to decode passowrd by: 0123                        # This is the password
PasswordType.OWNER_PASSWORD <enum 'PasswordType'> # I don't know how to check if it is OWER_PASSWORD or NOT_DECRYPTED
Trying to decode passowrd by: ghjk
PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED <enum 'PasswordType'>
Passwords tried: 6
Trying to decode passowrd by: dfgh
PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED <enum 'PasswordType'>
Passwords tried: 7
Trying to decode passowrd by: gfhj
PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED <enum 'PasswordType'>
Passwords tried: 8
Trying to decode passowrd by: 0125
PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED <enum 'PasswordType'>
Passwords tried: 9
```

I tried a bunch of soutions nothing seems to work. My if statement doesn't make sense I know,but I don't kow how to retreive

```
import PyPDF2 as pd

# from enum import PasswordType
import enum

filename = input('Path to the file: ')
filename = filename.strip()
file = open(filename,'rb')
pdfReader = pd.PdfReader(file)

tried = 0

if not pdfReader.is_encrypted:
    print('The file is not password protected! You can successfully open it!')

else:
    wordListFile = open('wordlist.txt', 'r',errors='ignore')
    body = wordListFile.read().lower()
    words = body.split('\n')


    for i in range(len(words)):
        word = words[i]
        print('Trying to decode passowrd by: {}'.format(word))
        result = pdfReader.decrypt(word)
        print(result,type(result))
        # try:
        if result == enum.Enum.PasswordType.OWNER_PASSWORD or result == enum.Enum.PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED :
            print('Success! The password is: '+ word)
            break
        # except:
        #     pass
        
        # try:
        elif result == enum.Enum.PasswordType.OWNER_PASSWORD or result == enum.Enum.PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED :
                    tried += 1
                    print('Passwords tried: ' + str(tried))
                    continue
        # except:
        #     pass
```

> Contents of wordlist.txt

```
hi
there
0002
0149
0489
0123
ghjk
dfgh
gfhj
0125
```

Comment: You can simply use `if result:` to check the success of the decryption.  The `PasswordType` Enum has a value of zero for the `NOT_DECRYPTED` case, and non-zero values for the two successful cases.

Comment: Thanks It worked out. But I also wanted to know how can I do specific comparison to `NOT_DECRYPTED` and `OWNER_PASSWORD`

Comment: Try `pd.PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PasswordType` enum in PyPDF is:

```
class PasswordType(IntEnum):
    NOT_DECRYPTED = 0
    USER_PASSWORD = 1
    OWNER_PASSWORD = 2
```

So the `PasswordType` members are both `PasswordType` and `int` -- so you have  a choice:

```
result = pdfReader.decrypt(word)

# old way
if result == 0:  # not decrypted
    ...

# new way
if result is PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I am still getting ModuleNotFound error. I tried importing the following "from enum.Enum import PasswordType" , "import PasswordType" and "from enum import PasswordType" . Can u plz help me with what should be imported or what should I include?

Comment: @IffatHumaira:  Sorry, it should be `pd.PasswordType.NOT_DECRYPTED`.